# Why is Google Maps iOS SDK crashing my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

Here is the output I get with the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57E1066F-07A5-4A41-B1AF-2B88F6B8300A//GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57E1066F-07A5-4A41-B1AF-2B88F6B8300A/.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57E1066F-07A5-4A41-B1AF-2B88F6B8300A/.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
2018-09-18 11:18:28.144990-0500 [7976:1906621] [framework] CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0
2018-09-18 11:18:28.331857-0500 [7976:1906844] ((null)) was false: Cannot find image polyline_colors_texture_dim
2018-09-18 11:18:28.331887-0500 [7976:1906844] ((null)) was false: Image data can't be NULL.
2018-09-18 11:18:28.331900-0500 [7976:1906844] ((null)) was false: Invalid texture state for routesDimTextureState.
```

I'm running iOS 12 SDK, on an iPhone X device and simulator.

It seems the way to reproduce it in my app is to build and run the app. Usually the map works fine at this point. Then I stop the running, and re-run it. Then when I try to load the map, I get this error with a crash. If

I've tried this on multiple versions of GoogleMaps using cocoapods, including the latest one.

I also know that this is an ongoing issue for the CoreData annotation, but I believe it is the last three lines that are crashing the app.

Also, I have a verified API Key, and iOS SDK is enabled. I am still using a transitional billing account though, but not sure if that is relevant.

UPDATE:
I downloaded Xcode 9.4 and I do no have this issue. The Core Data annotations are still there, but no crash.

UPDATE #2: 
I have found a work around. 
I believe this is caused by Xcode 10s new Build System. With Xcode window in focus, got to File -> Workspace Settings... -> Choose Legacy Build System.

I ended up digging through the assembly and found the path to the file it could NOT find. I went there, and the image is there. So either Google Maps bundle is configured incorrectly, or this is a bug with Cocoa Pods, or idk what.

Comment: I have the same problem when using Xcode 10, any solution?

Comment: @MingChu just provided a second update in my post. After spending 7 hours yesterday digging through assembly, the work around was a simple as using the legacy builder.

Comment: @MingChu I've added an issue to Google's Issue Tracker, please star it if you'd like to keep up with the status on it and to show that this issue is affecting you as well: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116217655

Comment: Just FYI, I tried creating a new project using Xcode 10, pod init -> add "pod 'GoogleMaps'" to Podfile -> pod install and it works 

Comment: My testing project: https://github.com/ming-chu/TestGoogleMap

Comment: @MingChu see my answer below. Make sure in your original project you don't have an older version of google maps installed manually.

Comment: Thanks jped, I checked that it only installed via cocoapods, that's so weird.

Comment: My app crashes instantly if I have a foreign letter in my product name (app name). The letters Ø and Æ are causing this somehow..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. The reason it was crashing was because a previous developer had installed GMAPS SDK manually and did not remove it when switching to cocoapods. I fixed it by opening the Frameworks folder that's inside of my apps project (not the one inside of Pods) and deleting all the google maps stuff. And now it works with the new Xcode 10 build system.

Answer (score 1):

Copy Bundle resources found in the Build Phase might contain a file listed under `GoogleMaps.bundle` label. I also deleted this file

Comment: This is probably better as a comment rather than as an answer.

Comment: apologize I tried to add it as a comment but I don't enough StackOverflow points 